# Get address out of a paragraph with regex

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, street-address

Alright, this one's a bit of a pain.  I'm doing some scraping with Python, trying to get an address out of a few lines of poorly tagged HTML.  Here's a sample of the format:

```
256-555-5555<br/>
1234 Fake Ave S<br/>
Gotham (Lower Ward)<br/>
```

I'd like to retrieve only `1234 Fake Ave S, Gotham`.  Any ideas?  I've been doing regex's all night and now my brain is mush...

Edit:
More detail about what the possible scenarios of how the data will arrive.  Sometimes the first line will be there, sometimes not.  All of the addresses I have seen have Ave, Way, St in it although I would prefer not to use that as a factor in the selection as I am not certain they will always be that way.  The second and third line are alPhone (or possible email or website):

What I had in mind was something that

1. Selects everything on 2nd to last line (so, second line if there are three lines, first line if just two when there isn't a phone number).
2. Selects everything on last line that isn't in parentheses.
3. Combine the 2nd to last line and last line, adding a ", " in between the two.

I'm using Scrapy to acquire the HTML code.  The address is all in the same div, I want to use regex to further break the data up into appropriate sections.  Now how to do that is what I'm unable to figure out.

Edit2:

As per Ofir's comment, I should mention that I have already made expressions to isolate the phone number and parentheses section.

Phone (or possible email or website):

```
((1[-. ])?[0-9]{3}[-. ])?\(?([0-9]{3}[-. ][A?([0-9]{4})|([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)|(www.+)|([\w\.-]*(?:com|net|org|us))
```

parentheses:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

I'm not sure how to use those to construct a everything-but-these statement.

Comment: How would you specify "address"? Please give an in detail description of your input and output format. And consider a html-parser.

Comment: skip regexps and move over to an proper html-parser like beautifulsoup

Comment: I'm actually using Scrapy to do the scraping.  I should have gone into more detail, I've updated the description.

Comment: That's still not enough - add a couple more examples, or describe verbally what you need. Anything after a line with only numbers and dashes, elide any parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that in your case it is easier to focus on what you don't want:

- html tags (`<br>`)
- phone numbers
- everything in parenthesis

Each of which can be matched easily with simple regular expressions, making it easy to construct one to match the rest (presumably - the address)

Comment: This is a good idea.  I should mention that I've already written out regular expressions to isolate the data for both the phone numbers and parentheses.  I've updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

This attempts to isolate the last two lines out of the string:

```
>>> s="""256-555-5555<br/>
... 1234 Fake Ave S<br/>
... Gotham (Lower Ward)<br/>
... """
>>> m = re.search(r'((?!</br>).*)<br/>\n((?!</br>).*)<br/>$)', s)
>>> print m.group(1)
1234 Fake Ave S
```

Trimming the parentheses is probably best left to a separate line of code, rather than complicating the regular expression further.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you problem, I think you are taking the wrong way to solve it.

Regexes are not a magical tool that could extract pertinent data from a pulp and jumble of undifferentiated elements of text. It is a tool that can only extract data from a text having variable parts but also a minimum of stable structure acting as anchors relatively to which the variable parts can be localized.

In your treatment, it seems to me that you first isolated this part containing possible phone number followed by address on 1/2 lines. But doing so, you lost information: what is before and what is after is anchoring information, you shouldn't try to find something in the remaining section obtained after having eliminated this information.

Moreover, I presume that you don't want only to catch a phone number and an address: you may want to extract other pieces of information lying before and after this section. With a good shaped regex, you could capture all the pieces in one shot.

So, please, give more of the text, with enough characters before and enough characters after the limited section  allowing to write a correct and easier regex strategy to catch all the data you want. triplee has already asked you that, and you didn't, why ?